# how to find source of error on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku that I don't visit very often. When I visited it today, I got the standard Rails error message

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I ran `heroku logs` to try to figure out what the problem was, but the logs don't say anything that would explain the error (to me).

What do you do in this situation?

```
2013-11-04T22:52:07.048102+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2013-11-04T22:52:07.132891+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (13.2ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.133396+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.146333+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.147977+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.148485+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.4ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.151556+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.175334+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (12.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.183576+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.188420+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.212161+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.212742+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.4ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.226959+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.246992+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.243411+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.296351+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.297843+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered shared/_analytics.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.308385+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/_total.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.399532+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (311.6ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.399720+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 351ms
2013-11-04T22:52:07.398061+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (44.1ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.429348+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.429836+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.3ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.428209+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (1.3ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.430004+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.737679+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.2ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.733934+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (303.5ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.734305+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.741156+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (314.7ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.740339+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.842689+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to myemail@gmail.com (67ms)
2013-11-04T22:52:07.842689+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: did you get the ExceptionNotification email with the error report? (which it says it sent) You should get a full stack trace in there as well that you can share.

Comment: the logs say an email was sent (I think I have an email registered in the app) but I didn't get one, do I have to configure it somehow for  it to send?

Comment: the exception_notification README shows you how to configure the middleware, and add a recipient email address. https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/blob/master/README#L21

Comment: you can also tail heroku logs with `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: It's not configured right to send the email

Comment: can you update the email and repro the error? or tail the logs and copy the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a free version of one of the logging add-ons like Papertrail. Try them all out and see which you prefer.

If you want an E-mail, I don't think you can configure an error E-mail through Heroku *per se*, but you can use the free version of the Sendgrid add-on to send error information to yourself in a `rescue` block or `rescue_from Exception, :with => :email_error_info` in your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I installed it and it's telling me the same thing I posted in the OP.

Comment: Did you execute the same commands or actions to reproduce the error and *then* look at the logs? If so and you still see nothing, make sure you aren't swallowing error information in a `rescue` block somewhere.